# Ruby on Rails Model creation string not converted to integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

Here is my code:
base_release_id column in release db is integer type

form.html.haml

```
= form_for @release  do |f| 
  = f.label :name
  %br
  = f.text_field :name
  ....
  = f.label :base_release_id
  %br
  = f.select :base_release_id, options_from_collection_for_select(conditionsPlusBlankOrderBy(Release),"id","name",@release.base_release_id)
  = f.submit
```

releases_controller.rb

```
 def create
    ap params
    @release = Release.new(params[:release])
    ap @release
    ...
  end
```

I was going to create a new release including its name , base release id etc.
I was using 2 "ap" to trace the release object. strange thing happen. See my log below:

```
 {
                  "utf8" => "â",
    "authenticity_token" => "8HdDlC3jJxYvq+8tUh/cut5ibHxjIF6L2CzAFORlNBg=",
               "release" => {
                   "name" => "e",
                   "code" => "e",
        "base_release_id" => "2"
    },
                "commit" => "Create Release",
                "action" => "create",
            "controller" => "releases"
}
#<Release:0x000000190f06b8> {
                 :id => nil,
               :name => "e",
               :code => "e",
    :base_release_id => nil,
}
 Processing by ReleasesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"â", "authenticity_token"=>"8HdDlC3jJxYvq+8tUh/cut5ibHxjIF6L2CzAFORlNBg=", "release"=>{"name"=>"e", "code"=>"e", "base_release_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Create Release"}
```

Not sure why base_release_id lost, name and code is working.
I have the similar code works in other page, in which case parame string value don't parsed to model integer?

it works if i added the datatype convertion as below:

```
def create
        ap params
        @release = Release.new(params[:release])
        @release.base_release_id = params[:release][:base_release_id].to_i if params[:release][:base_release_id]
        ap @release
        ...
      end
```

Please help and thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using rails 4+ ?
`params.require(:release).permit(Release.fields.keys)`

Comment: Actually, my instance is running on rails 3.0.9, but when i type rails -v in my console, it gives me 4.0.2.   
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: what about `bundle exec rails -v`
Maybe it's an rvm/bundler issue.

Comment: Try `Release.new(params.require(:release).permit(Release.fields.keys)`
instead of `Release.new(params[:release])`

Comment: bundle exec gave me Rails 3.0.9

Comment: TypeError (can't convert Symbol into String):
  activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'

Comment: Start rails with command: `bundle exec rails s`
And return the old statement
`@release = Release.new(params[:release])`

Comment: found why. in my model release.rb, i'v defined "attr_accessible :id, :name, :code, :as => :tmp_use". Then it accept id, name and code only. After i added :base_release_id, it works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found why. 
in my model release.rb, i'v defined "attr_accessible :id, :name, :code, :as => :tmp_use". Then it accept id, name and code only. After i added :base_release_id, it works.

not sure how :as => :tmp_use work. I suppose default all variable can be accessed. In some places, i was using
Release.new("id"=>row[:id],"name"=>row[:name],"code"=>row[:code], :as => :tmp_use)
Some places i don't want to do it i want to all columns be accessable.

No sure how.

Thank you Ivan anyway.